# Instanciate new AuthorizationServerProvider when per http request using dependency injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have a web api 2 project and I am using Asp.net Identity and Entity framework.
I have discovered that when I change the password, the old one still works but the new one give me error (invalid grant).

I am sure the change password works correctly... Infact in the database the value of the (hashed) password changes correctly.

**UPDATE**

I have understood why. The `authorizationServerProvider` (or the user manager I use inside it) is not instanciated per http request. It seems it is a singleton. The problem is that it is instanciated on startup and stop, so it's like it continue to use data of the first login, that are cached (by Entity framework).

Here how I configure my `authorizationServerProvider`  class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oauthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            //...,
            Provider = new TokenBasedAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oauthServerOptions);
    }
```

How can avoid the login use the cached data?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you are not disposing UnitOfWork / context. How do you initialize UnitOfWork / context?

Comment: I am sing Windsor Castle... `UnitOfWork` and the `dbContext` are set `LifestyleTransient` infact, if I debug, I correctly go inside the `Dispose` method of the `UnitOfWork` and of my `dbContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

- Disable Tracking using AsNoTracking()
- Throw away the DbContext and create a new one
- Call GetDatabaseValues() to get updated values for single entity

Comment: I have already thrown the DbContext... and I create a new one for each http request... In fact when I do a new HttpRequest (the login), I pass from the new of the DbContext

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with UseOAuthAuthorizationServer and DI. Last time I faced with this when using Autofac but this is relevant to other DI frameworks. The problem is we have static instance of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider stored by middleware so no DI involved.
My solution was to get dependencies in OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in each methods like this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var scope = context.OwinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope();
    var userManager = scope.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>();

    .........
}
```

My container initialization:

```
    public static IContainer Configure(IAppBuilder appBuilder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        .... registrations here ....

        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

        return container;
    }
```

You can do something like this using other DI containers as well.